# Simulation of Bernoulli essays

Tags: r, algorithm, plot, statistics, simulation

Consider a fair coin. Let Hn=0 if you observe tail and Hn=1 is you observe face. Then P(Hn=0)=P(Hn=1)=1/2.

The distribution of Sn=H1+...+Hn is binomial with parameters n and p=1/2.

We use this distribution to find probabilities for Yn=Sn/n, which is the proportion of faces.

Simulate this in r.

Here is my approach to implement this algorithm in R (not sure if it's correct according to the text, please check it):

```
n=1000
h=rbinom(n,1,1/2)
y=cumsum(h)/n
plot(n,y)
```

When I run the program, marks an error

> plot(n,y)
>
> Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
>     'x' and 'y' lengths differ

I don't understand why since `n=1000` and when I type `y` to know how many elements has returned `1000` values.

Why am I getting the error then?

Comment: `n` is length 1 and `y` is length 1000.

Comment: `n = 1000`, yes, but _`length(n) = 1`_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`n = 1000`, as numeric. So:

`1:n` => `c(1, 2, 3, ..., 998, 999, 1000)`

```
plot(1:n,y)
```

[image]